# Employee Register using sql server to present,absent,holiday of each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1: Table I had for example one employee data

| EmployeeID | companyID | process date | DayStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 52 | 2022-01-01 | X |
| 1001 | 52 | 2022-01-02 | X |
| 1001 | 52 | 2022-01-03 | X |
| 1001 | 52 | 2022-01-04 | H |
| 1001 | 52 | 2022-01-05 | / |

Table 2: Need to show like this for multiple employees

| EmployeeID | companyID | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5... | D31 | Total Present | Total Holidays | Total absent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 52 | X | X | X | X | X | X | 26 | 4 | 0 |
| 1002 | 52 | A | X | X | X | X | X | 25 | 4 | 1 |
| 1003 | 52 | A | X | / | X | X | X | 24.5 | 4 | 1 |

I want this type table using SQL query.

I have employeeAttendatance table 1 and show data like table 2

Comment: First of all decide on _which RDBMS_ you are going to use and then _which language_.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to write SQL code, particularly for the actual database you're using.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes but i don't kown how to pivot this table for each employee.I hope your expert into sql database so you can me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sql [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16). But there is a trick with the date columns. If they where static that would be no problem and you can do that like this:

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT EmployeeID,CompanyID,[process date],DayStatus FROM dbo.Employee )
AS source
PIVOT
(
 Max(DayStatus) 
  FOR [process date] IN ( [2022-01-01],[2022-01-02],[2022-01-03],[2022-01-04],[2022-01-05])
)AS PivotTable
```

But if they are dynamic you should combine the solution with dynamic sql:

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

, @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

```
SET @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[process date])
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT [process date]
                FROM Employee
                ) c
            ORDER BY [process date]
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

            SET @cols2 = STUFF((
            SELECT ',[' + c.[process date]+'] as D'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [process date]) AS VARCHAR(4))
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT [process date]
                FROM Employee
                ) c
            ORDER BY [process date]
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
          
         SELECT(@cols2)

SET @query = N'SELECT EmployeeID,CompanyID,'+@cols2+'
,(select count([DayStatus]) from Employee e2 where e2.DayStatus =''X'' and e2.EmployeeID=EmployeeID) Xdays
from
(SELECT EmployeeID,CompanyID,[process date],DayStatus FROM dbo.Employee )
AS source
PIVOT
(
 Max(DayStatus) 
  FOR [process date] IN ( '+@cols+')
)AS PivotTable
';

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Comment: Yes i try this but i had dynamic date columns

Comment: I added the dynamic part too

Comment: Thanks for your response but how to get count of each employee like total present ,absent,holiday days

Comment: You can simply add some sub queries to the line `SET @query = N'SELECT * from` e.g.
`SET @query = N'SELECT PivotTable.*,(select count([process date]) from Employee e2 where e2.DayStatus =''X'' and e2.EmployeeID=PivotTable.EmployeeID) Xdays from ...`

Comment: Get error. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

Comment: One small request can we change dynamic date columns into D1,D2,D3..D31

Comment: OK I added some more details to the answer

Comment: perfect.. but DayStatus get value 0 not 'X'

Comment: Any update about dayStatus

Comment: Edited again! hope this would be the final version :))

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '2022-08-01'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '2022-08-02'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '2022-08-03'.

So on

Date column not match :)